# Databricks format in Pyspark to write in Redshift

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, aws-glue, spark-redshift, aws-emr-studio

I am migrating data from postgres to redshift by using jdbc format but for the redshift if I ise jdbc format then some of the options are not available like escape.
So I thought to use format `com.databricks.spark.redshift` to write by using pyspark. I am using AWS EMR.
So can you please help me how to use this format or what packages and jars I need to install to run by the above mentioned format?

Thanks.